# Fetch data in the mentioned scenario using a single MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables with column titles:

```
course_test_status
------------------
testid
testname
testdesc

student_login
--------------
stuid
stuname 


student_test_status
-------------------
testid
stuid
```

I want to fetch stuname and testname using **single query** if i already have stuid and testid available. 
Second thing I would like to know is that which way would be faster? Using select query two times (once with stuid and another with testid) or using a single complex (With Joins or whatever you are suggesting) query?

Comment: Gosh, if you are asking about which method would be faster, could you please show the queries that you are considering?  Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: See, basically I need testname and stuname in PHP variables. I can simply `SELECT stuname FROM student_login WHERE stuid=?` and then `SELECT testname FROM course_test_status WHERE testid=?` to get the values. 
I am asking will this be alright performance wise or you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say a single call is always better, and probably faster, than multiple calls

```
SELECT s.stuname, c.testname
FROM student_test_status s
JOIN course_test_status c ON c.testid = s.testid
JOIN student_login l ON l.stuid = s.stuid
```

Comment: Oh brilliant! 
A little modification to your query worked for me.
`SELECT stuname,testname
FROM student_test_status s
JOIN course_test_status c ON c.testid = s.testid
JOIN student_login_zbzxs l ON l.stuid = s.stuid WHERE s.testid=33 AND s.stuid=2`